# undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass within Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep getting the error message `undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass` whenever this section of code is being run and the value is not present:

```
module VideosHelper
 def youtube_embed(url, **kwargs)
  uri = URI('//www.youtube.com/embed/')
  uri.path += find_youtube_id(url).join("','")
  options = {
    src: uri.to_s,
    width: '100%',
    height: '350px',
    frameborder: 0,
    allowfullscreen: true
  }
  content_tag(:iframe, nil, options.merge(kwargs), false)
end

def find_youtube_id(url)
  uri = URI(url)
  CGI.parse(uri.query).try(:[], 'v')
rescue URI::InvalidURIError
  nil
end
end
```

It's specifically the line with parse. I thought .try would resolve it. I've even used .fetch instead of .try and the same issue persists.

EDIT: Included in this the full code for the helper file. Originally in the find_youtube_id method I actually had only nil after rescue and was messing with it.

Here is what's present in my terminal

```
.container.video-section
 .row.video-group
  .col-md-8
    - unless @region.youtube_url.nil?
     = youtube_embed(@region.youtube_url)
  .col-md-3.offset-md-1.sales-group.text-center
    .manager-single
      = image_tag @region.staff_photo.url, class: 'img-fluid'
app/helpers/videos_helper.rb:17:in `find_youtube_id'
app/helpers/videos_helper.rb:4:in `youtube_embed'
app/views/regions/show.html.slim:74:in `block in _ 
app_views_regions_show_html_slim__295776519867909611_70169935841560'
app/views/regions/show.html.slim:5:in `_ 
app_views_regions_show_html_slim__295776519867909611_70169935841560'
app/controllers/regions_controller.rb:14:in `show'
```

Comment: show the stacktrace. And value of `url` and `uri.query`. Also, that exception handler is weird. Not sure what you were hoping to accomplish with that.

Comment: hm, the first line of the stacktrace is not in CGI.parse or deeper? Interesting. Anyhow, the problems seems to be with bad data in `@region.youtube_url`. What values does it have?

Comment: This isn't really a Ruby question. It's a question of figuring out what you want to happen when the URL is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
CGI.parse(uri.query)
```

The `uri.query` is `nil` and the `parse` method tries to split it.

If you want to return `nil` when the value is not present, replace the line with:

```
CGI.parse(uri.query).try(:[], 'v') if uri.query
```

Comment: Same response actually.

Comment: Was literally about to try something like that.

Comment: Since OP clearly doesn't know how to handle `nil`, returning `nil` from here is just going to push the problem further away from the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Full code updated with answer.

```
module VideosHelper
 def youtube_embed(url, **kwargs)
   uri = URI('//www.youtube.com/embed/')
   uri.path += find_youtube_id(url).join("','") if uri.query
   options = {
     src: uri.to_s,
     width: '100%',
     height: '350px',
     frameborder: 0,
     allowfullscreen: true
   }
   content_tag(:iframe, nil, options.merge(kwargs), false)
 end

 def find_youtube_id(url)
   uri = URI(url)
   CGI.parse(uri.query).try(:[], 'v') if uri.query
 rescue URI::InvalidURIError
   nil
 end
end
```

When applying if uri.query to the end of CGI.parse it resolves the split issue but presented an issue on uri.path so duplicated the answer.